# About the usage of modal verb in conditional sentences

Tags: modal-verbs

> 1. Should the UK leave the EU with no agreement in place, economic growth **could** be stricken harder.
> 2. Should the UK leave the EU with no agreement in place, economic growth **can** be stricken harder.
> 3. Should the UK leave the EU with no agreement in place, economic growth **will** be stricken harder.
> 4. Should the UK leave the EU with no agreement in place, economic growth **might** be stricken harder.

Among all these modal verbs used, are there any differences, and what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"could" and "might" are used to express possibility and uncertainty. "It is possible that the economy could be damaged, but not certain."

"will" is used to express a more or less certain future. "The economy will certainly be damaged".

"can" is awkward, it would seem to suggest ability, but given the context the apparent meaning (we will be able to damage the economy) would be odd.